# How to create slide like UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to slide my view like elements are sliding in `UIScrollView`. An user can touch view and pull and, depending on acceleration and position, the view should leave or stay.

Should I use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

Comment: use UIScrollView why reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use **UIPanGestureRecognizer** if you want the content to follow the user's finger (sounds like you do here).  Swipe gesture will wait for the swipe to complete and then tell you about it.

Use the 'state' property to get the location of the finger when it starts, and when it finishes, and use velocity to determine acceleration.

`CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];`

```
if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
         startLocation = location;
}
  else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
      // Move view or do something to give feedback to user while they swipe
}
else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    CGPoint distanceMoved = CGPointMake(location.x - startLocation.x, location.y - startLocation.y);
    CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:self.view];
 // Logic goes here
}
```